# PHP move chosen files from A folder to B folder

Tags: php, copy, directory

This is a tricky one and I'm not sure where to start, so any help will be grateful.

I have a parent folder called 'source' (c:/dev/source) which contains several child folders.

I need a PHP script that will display the child folders with checkboxes next to each, and a text field for a new folder name, allowing users to tick the checkboxes of the ones they want to copy to a 'destination of c:/dev/destination/the_folder_name_they_typed_in

When they click submit, the selected child folders will be copied from c:/dev/source to c:/dev/destination/the_folder_name_they_typed_in

This is all running on a local internal development server. The child folders will always be in c:/dev/source/

Comment: Start with the [php `rename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a not well known little bit of code called DirectoryIterator. It's not fully documented on the PHP site, but heres the jist of it:

Create a list of files and folders with checkboxes next to them, slap them all in an array.

```
$Directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('c:/dev/source');
$Iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($Directory);    

?><form method="post"><?
foreach($Iterator  as $r){

       if($r->isDot()) continue;

       echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"copy[]\" value=\"".($r->getSubPathName())."\"> ".$r->getSubPathName() . " <br>";

}
?></form><?
```

---

Now add this part to the top of the file

```
<?php 
if($_POST){
if(is_array($_POST['copy'])) foreach($_POST['copy'] as $c){
 @copy($c, str_replace('c:/dev/source','c:/dev/dest', $c));
  echo "copied: $c to ". str_replace('c:/dev/source','c:/dev/dest', $c) . "<br>";

}
}
```

I'm not fully sure what result you get from `$r->getSubPathName()` can you let me know if it outputs an array? if so it might be that you replace that with $r->getSubPath() and then add the "c:/dev/source" to the variable $c when you copy it?

## Further Reading:

[here](http://www.phpro.org/examples/Recursively-Rename-All-Files-In-Directory-With-RecursiveDirectoryIterator.html)

Comment: Thanks Jason. It threw an error though:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method SplFileInfo::isDot()

Comment: What version of PHP are you running @PHPnoob?

Answer (score 1):

Somme advice:

**Use a whitelist** for allowed characters in destination folder. Only commit the operation if it matches:

```
^[a-z0-9_-]+$
```

You can use **array indices** for directory names. This way you can iterate thru the ckeckboxes with `foreach ($_POST["dirs"]) { ... }`

```
<input type="checkbox" name="dirs[directory_name]"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="dirs[other_dir_name]"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="dirs[third_directory_name]"/>
```

Always **checkthe directory names against a whitelist** like above. (If you allow characters like `.` or `/` or many other it can be a security risk).